# What is the purpose of ISOCountryCode field in Validate Phone Number API - AWS-Pinpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I am using AWS Javascript SDK to validate phone number, the payload is like this

```
{
  "IsoCountryCode": "string",
  "PhoneNumber": "string"
}
```

In the docs, its mentioned that providing a country code in `PhoneNumber` field is mandatory, which is clear. But I didn't understand the purpose of providing `IsoCountryCode`. I tried running the api without this field and it worked fine.

**What purpose does it serve? is it even mandatory?**

Comment: Good question. I am looking into this using the AWS SDK

Answer (score 1):

I tested with the AWS SDK for Java V2. In the Javadocs - it is defined as:

The two-character code, in ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 format, for the country or region where the phone number was originally registered.

However, this value does not seem to be required to make the call. As you can see below in my screen shot, i commented out this value and the call was successful. As you can see, I got back information about my number such as the carrier, etc.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I also verified it, though it seems odd that the parameter would be completely useless, perhaps, just for docs/logs?